# Binding to Twitter's Follow event isn't working

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to bind to my Follow button to a function by using

```
twttr.events.bind('follow', function (event) {
    alert('Followed!!!');
});
```

Unfortunately when I actually click Follow, and make sure I follow on twitter, the function is not being called.

Anything I'm missing (or perhaps a better way to debug this)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to put those events within a twttr.ready event:

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind('follow', function (event) {
        alert('Followed!!!');
    });
});
```

Now that works.